# Rational curves that cover a degree $n$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a general degree $n$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Let $d$ be the smallest integer such that $X$ is covered by genus-zero curves (possibly reducible) of degree $d$. Do we know an upper bound for $d$?

Comment: Adjunction should give $d\le n$, and   Miyaoka-Mori should give the converse.

Comment: A general hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is covered by conics.

Comment: As @abx writes, a general hypersurface of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is covered by conics.  As proved first by Yi Zhu, and later proved in a different way by Zhiyu Tian, a sufficiently general chain of conics deforms to a "very free" rational curve in the hypersurface.